# What passport strategy to use

Tags: passport.js, passport-local

I am building an e-commerce site and I'm having a hard time choosing between passport-local and passport-local-mongoose strategies. The first seems nice but the latter seem a bit confusing. I don't know, I'm feeling tempted to implement the auth system myself. Please what's your say on this, I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

They essentially work the same way, but `passport-local-mongoose` is built off of `passport-local` and abstracts out some of the setup to get passport up and running.

That being said I would recommend at least learning `passport-local` since its not that much more setup and it will allow you to better troubleshoot any issues that arise that would not be apparent if you were to just jump into `passport-local-mongoose`.